# Rails - Dynamic Dropdown lists with two models category & subcategory

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am working on a little project where people can send "product search messages" to a community. Therefore, they need to select to which category and subcategory their searched product belongs. To select it I just need two dropdown lists whereas the second dropdown list changes dynamically dependent on the first selection. 
I guess thats an easy task and I already feel like being close to a solution. 
I got two models (one for category, one for subcategories) that have a one-to-many relationship.

This is my code so far:

**my search_controller**

```
def index
  @subcategory = Subcategory.find_by("id = ?", params[:subcategory_id])
end

def new
      @search = Search.new
      @categories = Category.all
      @subcategories = Subcategory.where("category_id = ?", Category.first.id)    
end

def update_subcategories
    @subcategories = Subcategory.where("category_id = ?", params[:category_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end

def create 
  @search = current_user.searches.build(search_params) 
  @categories = Category.all
  if @search.save 
    redirect_to searches_path
  else 
    render 'new' 
  end 
end

private 
def search_params 
    params.require(:search).permit(:title, :category_id, :subcategory_id) 
end
```

**part of my routes.rb**

```
  get 'searches/update_subcategories', as: 'update_subcategories'
  get 'searches/new'
```

**The view on the searches/new page**

```
    <%= form_for(@search, method: :get ) do |f| %>  
<%= f.text_area :title %>
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(@categories.collect { |category| [category.name.titleize, category.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'categories_select' } %>

<%= f.select :subcategory_id, options_for_select(@subcategories.collect { |subcategory| [subcategory.name.titleize, subcategory.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'subcategories_select' } %>

<%= f.submit "Create" %> 
<% end %>
```

**A partial: views/subcategory/**

```
<option value="<%= subcategory.id %>"><%= subcategory.name.titleize %></option>
```

**And app/assets/javascripts/search.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#categories_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_subcategories',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        category_id: $("#categories_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic category select OK!")
```

**And app/views/searches/update_subcategories.js.coffee:**

```
$("#subcategories_select").empty()
  .append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @subcategories)) %>")
```

There is no error but the second dropdown list does not change. What am I missing?

I found this way on: https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/

I am thankful for any help!

Comment: I just went through this using select2 dropdowns, if that's what you're using I'll write up an answer just lmk.

Comment: I'm not using select2 no. I guess the mistake is in the last 4 code section because everything is working, only the second drop-down list is not reacting.